# Async await vs Promises vs Mapping?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How does one decide between promises, async awaits, and mapping operators like concatMap?

Here's my specific case, but I'm also curious about how you decide in general:

I am making an http call to my backend, and then I make another http call afterwards. When processing the json data from the second call, I need to use values that are returned by the first call. In this situation, is it better to use async await, a promise or concatMap? Also in general, what are the guidelines for deciding which to use?

Here is what I current have, using concatMap. (I am dynamically generating child components from my getTask http call, and each child component needs to have access to annotationFormats).

```
this.dashboardService.getAnnotationFormats()
    .pipe(
      concatMap(annotationFormats=> this.dashboardService.getTasks())
    )
    .subscribe(
      (tasks)=>{
          for(let task of tasks){
            const componentFactory=this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(DashboardItemComponent);
            const componentRef=this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
            componentRef.instance.task=task;
            componentRef.instance.annotationFormats=annotationFormats;
            componentRef.instance.compInteraction=this;
            this.taskRef.push(componentRef);
          }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async/await and promises are basically the same with different syntax. Asynchronous code that will run once after some job has been finished.

As a rule, I would never never use none of those while using Angular. Angular comes with RxJS out of the box, which is so much more than promises. You can use RxJS for running async code once when a job has completed, but it also gives you the possibility of creating streams of data and manipulating them in so many different ways. 
It does take a bit to fully understand RxJS and reactive programming but once you do you realize how much you can do with it.

In your case, I like to use the operator `forkJoin`, since the two requests seem independent from each other. You can give it a list of resources you want to obtain and will execute the async code in subscribe once they have all completed, which makes it perfect for http requests:

```
forkJoin({
  annotationFormats: this.dashboardService.getAnnotationFormats(),
  tasks: this.dashboardService.getTasks(),
})
.subscribe(
  ({tasks, annotationFormats})=>{
      for(let task of tasks){
        const componentFactory=this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(DashboardItemComponent);
        const componentRef=this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
        componentRef.instance.task=task;
        componentRef.instance.annotationFormats=annotationFormats;
        componentRef.instance.compInteraction=this;
        this.taskRef.push(componentRef);
      }
    }
);
```

Take your time to learn RxJS, I guarantee it will pay off. Whenever you are using RxJS and it feels too complex or wrong, that is because it probably is. Head to the RxJS documentation and look for something that might useful, and if you don't find anything a quick google search will probably get you the solution anyways. Point is, don't just use it blindly, always try to understand how it works.

I hope this is useful. :)

**Edit:**

For RxJS < 6.5, the syntax is a bit different:

```
forkJoin(
  this.dashboardService.getTasks(),
  this.dashboardService.getAnnotationFormats()
)
.subscribe(
  ([tasks, annotationFormats])=>{
      for(let task of tasks){
        const componentFactory=this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(DashboardItemComponent);
        const componentRef=this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
        componentRef.instance.task=task;
        componentRef.instance.annotationFormats=annotationFormats;
        componentRef.instance.compInteraction=this;
        this.taskRef.push(componentRef);
      }
    }
);
```

Notice we pass the resources as arguments, not as an object, and the result in the subscribe will be in an array form instead of an object too.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great!

Comment: Ah I am getting an error when I tried this code out: Argument of type '{ annotationFormats: Observable<AnnotationFormat[]>; tasks: Observable<Task[]>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'annotationFormats' does not exist in type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: Hey Shisui, sorry for the late reply. I have been testing my solution in a real scenario and it seems to be working fine, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-begdqr  (check the console). Maybe you can check what are the differences between that code and yours so we can spot the problem? I have never faced that error before.

Comment: Actually, checking at the documentation, the problem might be your rxjs version. Is it greater that 6.5? If it is not you will have to use a different syntax, I can update the original post with the other syntax.

Answer (score 0):

They have different use. async/await is used when you want to hold on a place where you have written some asynchronous code. while primises are tool to spot a place where async code is executed and invokes callback.